# Storing image matrix in MySQL using Matlab

Tags: mysql, matlab, jdbc

I am attempting to save an image matrix to my database. Having followed what was outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302487/storing-matlab-array-in-mysql-again), I run into the following error: `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 0 bytes is stored inline.`

The code causing the error is this:

```
            insertionMatrix = reshape(orgMatrix, 1, []);
            hdl = conn.Handle;
            insert = ['insert into test (Name, Image) values (?, ?)'];
            stmtObj = hdl.prepareStatement(insert);
            stmtObj.setObject(1, Name);
            stmtObj.setObject(2, insertionMatrix);
            stmtObj.execute;
```

The array I am trying to insert is `1x263169`, and the column type involved for the field I am trying to insert is `longblob`. The current row format for the table is dynamic.

Comment: Is it working when you try uploading the original image without reshaping?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75328/row-size-error-with-mysql  Maybe help

Comment: Thank you @DaveTheRave, your suggestion worked! I increased the `innodb_log_file_size` by a factor of 10 and I can now insert the image into the database. Much appreciated

Comment: @Hussein inserting the original image still led to the same error but after modifying the `innodb_log_file_size`, this now works, thanks